# java.io.InvalidClassException: cdfs.events.C; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -x, local class serialVersionUID = y

Tags: java, serialization

We have a super class cdfs.events.A which is serializable and a serialVersionUID defined inside the java file.

cdfs.events.B is not serializable and no serialVersionUID defined but inherits from cdfs.events.A
cdfs.events.C is not serializable and no serialVersionUID defined but inherits from cdfs.events.B

Everything was working fine until we modified cdfs.events.C (a minor logical change - we just made it an empty class), delivered and deployed in tomcat.

Now when the cdfs.events.C is tried to be created by the application we are getting this error,

*java.io.InvalidClassException: cdfs.events.C; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -1499697765910017945, local class serialVersionUID = 8422749130784877315*

The above serialVersionUIDs shown in error is also not among the base class serialVersionUID . So it means it is some generated ids but where is the old one interrupting.
There is no serialisation happening and we had done this before many times without issues. Also there is no client server model.
Please help

Comment: What is purpose of class `C`?

Comment: "cdfs.events.B is not serializable [...] but inherits from cdfs.events.A" is not possible if A is serializeable. Since `Serializable` is an interface and you can't "un-implement" an interface in a derived class `B` (and C) **does** implement the interface and is therefore considered serializable. The most likely reason for serialization to happen when you don't use it explicitly in this case is session serialization (is a C instance ever put into a session?)